# Disable text selection when double clicking

Tags: javascript, gwt, double-click

I'm working in a GWT app that will have two RichTextAreas. In each of them there will be the same sentence, but in different languages. When the user clicks in a word it will be highlighted together with its correspondence in the other RichTextArea. When a user double clicks in a word, instead of the words, their chunks will be highlighted. Because of the double click event is never raised (I don't know why) I created my own class, which extends RichTextArea and I raised myself the double click event (depending of the time passed between two clicks).

The problem is that I can't disable default text selection. I've been searching for possible solutions but I didn't found any that actually worked. I've tried with both CSS and JavaScript. This is how my class looks like:

```
public class MyRichTextArea extends RichTextArea
{
    private boolean clickedOnce = false;
    private int msDelay = 250;

    public MyRichTextArea()
    {
        sinkEvents(Event.ONMOUSEDOWN);
                disableTextSelectInternal(this.getElement());
    }

    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event)
        {
        switch (DOM.eventGetType(event))
        {
            case Event.ONMOUSEDOWN:
                if (!clickedOnce)
                {
                    clickedOnce = true;
                    Timer t = new Timer() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            if (clickedOnce)
                            {
                                clickedOnce = false;
                                raiseEvent(1);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    t.schedule(msDelay);
                }
                else
                {
                    clickedOnce = false;
                    raiseEvent(2);
                }
                //DOM.eventPreventDefault(event);
                break; 

        }
    }

    public void raiseEvent(int clickCount)
    {
        if (clickCount == 1)
        {
            this.fireEvent( new GwtEvent<ClickHandler>() 
                {
                    public com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.Type<ClickHandler> getAssociatedType() 
                    {
                        return ClickEvent.getType();
                    }

                    protected void dispatch(ClickHandler handler) 
                    {
                        handler.onClick(null);
                    }
                });
        }
        else
        {
            this.fireEvent( new GwtEvent<DoubleClickHandler>() 
                    {
                        public com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.Type<DoubleClickHandler> getAssociatedType() 
                        {
                            return DoubleClickEvent.getType();
                        }

                        protected void dispatch(DoubleClickHandler handler) 
                        {
                            handler.onDoubleClick(null);
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    protected native static void disableTextSelectInternal(Element e)
    /*-{
            e.ondrag = function () { return false; };
            e.onselectstart = function () { return false; };
            e.onmousedown = function () { return false; }
            e.style.MozUserSelect="none"
    }-*/;
}
```

I picked that method from here: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.org.google.gwt/49564, but it doesn't work to me. I guess this will have to be done with JavaScript. I'm a bit newbie in JavaScript and I don't know where to start from. If anyone has faced this problem before or has any possible solution, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/826782/681807

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for CSS tags.  They are as follows:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

In order to implement them into your object through java, you're looking for something like this:

```
MyRichTextArea myRichTextArea = new MyRichTextArea();
myRichTextArea.getElement().setAttribute("style",
    myRichTextArea.getElement().getAttribute("style") +
" -webkit-touch-callout: none;" +
" -webkit-user-select: none;" +
" -khtml-user-select: none;" +
" -moz-user-select: none;" +
" -ms-user-select: none;" +
" user-select: none;");
```

This appends the CSS above with the already set CSS of the element.  Hope this is the answer you're looking for!